# Is this the Melvin metric (magnetic universe) in disguise?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, magnetic-fields, symmetry, metric-tensor

I'm solving the Einstein equation assuming a cylindrical symmetry and found something interesting which I never saw elsewhere.  I now feel that I may have found the **Melvin magnetic universe** solution in another form but need a confirmation (sorry for the lengthy exposition below).  Assume the following metric (a cylindrical universe):
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2(t) g^2(r)(dx^2 + dy^2) - b^2(t) \, dz^2,
\end{equation}
where $a(t)$, $b(t)$ and $g(r)$ are unknown functions.  Of course: $r =\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and we could use $dx^2 + dy^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d\varphi^2$.  I want an *homogeneous* and *isotropic* spatial section in the plane $x \, y$, so the function $g(r)$ isn't completely arbitrary.  Calculating the Riemann tensor give these components (here, $i, j, k = 1, 2$ only, for the coordinates $x$ and $y$):
\begin{align}
R^0_{i 0 j} &= a \ddot{a} \, g^2 \, \delta_{ij}, \\[12pt]
R^0_{303} &= b \ddot{b}, \\[12pt]
R^i_{33j} &= -\, \frac{\dot{a} \dot{b} b}{a} \, \delta_{ij}, \\[12pt]
R^i_{jkl} &= (\dot{a}^2 g^2 + \mathcal{Q}(r))(\delta_{ki} \, \delta_{lj} - \delta_{li} \, \delta_{kj}) + \text{anisotropic terms}.
\end{align}
The anisotropic terms cancel if
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\frac{g^{\prime \prime}}{g} = \frac{g^{\prime}}{g \, r} + 2 \frac{g^{\prime 2}}{g^2},
\end{equation}
which implies the solution
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
g(r) = \frac{A}{1 + B \, r^2},
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $B$ are constants (they can be absorbed into the coordinates, so I'll take $A = 1$).  Then
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\mathcal{Q}(r) = 4 B \, g^2.
\end{equation}
Note that if $B$ is positive, then the whole $x \, y$ plane has a *finite area*: $\mathcal{A}_{x y} = \frac{\pi}{B}$ (that plane is *compact*)!  The components of the Einstein tensor could be calculated without troubles (again, $i, j = 1, 2$ only):
\begin{align}
G_{00} &= -\, \Big( 2 \frac{\dot{a} \dot{b}}{a b} + \frac{\dot{a}^2}{a^2} + \frac{4 B}{a^2} \Big), \tag{5} \\[12pt]
G_{ij} &= -\, \Big( \frac{\ddot{a}}{a} + \frac{\ddot{b}}{b} + \frac{\dot{a} \dot{b}}{a b} \Big) \, g_{ij}, \tag{6} \\[12pt]
G_{33} &= -\, \Big( 2 \frac{\ddot{a}}{a} + \frac{\dot{a}^2}{a^2} + \frac{4 B}{a^2} \Big) \, g_{33}. \tag{7}
\end{align}
I then need an anisotropic (i.e. cylindrical) perfect fluid stress-tensor, of components
\begin{equation}\tag{8}
T_{\mu \nu} = (\rho + \sigma) \, u_{\mu} u_{\nu} + (p - \sigma) \, n_{\mu} n_{\nu} - \sigma \, g_{\mu \nu},
\end{equation}
where $p \equiv p_{\parallel}$ and $\sigma \equiv p_{\perp}$ are the pressure along the $z$ axis and in the plane $x \, y$, respectively.  The fluid four-velocity is $u^{\mu} = (1, 0, 0, 0)$ (such that $u_{\mu} \, u^{\mu} = 1$) and the symmetry axis is represented by the spacelike four-vector $n^{\mu} = (0, 0, 0, 1/b(t))$ (such that $n_{\mu}\, n^{\mu} = -1$).  The local conservation of fluid $\nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu \nu} = 0$ implies the following:
\begin{equation}\tag{9}
\dot{\rho} + \Big( 2 \frac{\dot{a}}{a} + \frac{\dot{b}}{b} \Big) \rho + \frac{\dot{b}}{b} p + 2 \frac{\dot{a}}{a} \sigma = 0.
\end{equation}
Take note that a *purely magnetic field* could be cast into (8):
\begin{equation}
T_{\mu \nu} = F_{\mu \lambda} F^{\lambda}_{\; \; \nu}+ \frac{1}{4}
 g_{\mu \nu} F_{\lambda \kappa} F^{\lambda \kappa},
\end{equation}
with $F_{12}$ the only component.  We then have $p = -\, \rho$ (negative pressure = *tension* along the magnetic field lines) and $\sigma = + \rho$, such that the trace of (8) cancels: $g^{\mu \nu} T_{\mu \nu} = \rho - p - 2 \sigma = 0$.  Equ. (9) then implies the standard energy density of radiation in cosmology:
\begin{equation}\tag{10}
\rho(t) = \frac{\text{cste}}{a^4(t)}.
\end{equation}
Putting all these into Einstein equation $G_{\mu \nu} = -\, 8 \pi G \, T_{\mu \nu}$ give the following equations to be solved:
\begin{align}
2 \frac{\dot{a} \dot{b}}{a b} + \frac{\dot{a}^2}{a^2} + \frac{4 B}{a^2} = 8 \pi G \rho, \tag{11} \\[12pt]
\frac{\ddot{a}}{a} + \frac{\ddot{b}}{b} + \frac{\dot{a} \dot{b}}{a b} = -\, 8 \pi G \sigma = -\, 8 \pi G \rho, \tag{12} \\[12pt]
2 \frac{\ddot{a}}{a} + \frac{\dot{a}^2}{a^2} + \frac{4 B}{a^2} = -\, 8 \pi G p = +\, 8 \pi G \rho. \tag{13}
\end{align}
If the constant $B$ is positive, solving these give $a(t) = \text{cste}$ (so $\rho = \text{cste}$ !) and $b(t) = \sin{\omega t}$ (for $0 < \omega t < \pi$, where $\omega = \sqrt{8 \pi G \rho}$).

I'm perplexed by this solution, which appears to describe a *magnetic universe*, *homogeneous*, *isotropic* and *static* in the plane $x \, y$, and expanding/contracting along the $z$ axis.

Is this the *Melvin's magnetic universe* in another form?  Usually, Melvin's universe is described by the following *static* metric:
\begin{equation}\tag{14}
ds^2 = \Phi^2(r) (dt^2 - dr^2 - dz^2) - \frac{1}{\Phi^2(r)} \, r^2 d\varphi^2,
\end{equation}
where $\Phi(r) = 1 + C \, r^2$ (this function is similar to (3) above).

So how can I verify that metric (1) is equivalent to metric (14)?
\begin{equation}\tag{15}
ds^2 = d\tilde{t}^2 - \frac{1}{(1 + B \, \tilde{r}^2)^2}(d\tilde{r}^2 + \tilde{r}^2 \, d\varphi^2) - \sin^2{\omega \tilde{t}} \, d\tilde{z}^2.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **not a Melvin's magnetic universe** but *Bertotti–Robinson spacetime* which is simply a product $\text{AdS}_2 \times S_2$ of two-dimensional anti-de Sitter spacetime and a sphere.

Equation (3) together with the $a(t)$ being constant makes this a product spacetime and the line element of $ds_{2}^2=g(r)^2 (dx^2+dy^2)$ is a metric of $S_2$ or $H_2$ (depending on the sign of $B$) in stereographic projection.

The $t$–$z$ part is simply a $\text{AdS}_2$ metric. In higher dimensions this coordinate choice produces hyperbolic spatial slices.

The isometry group of such spacetime is a product $SO(2,1)\times SO(3)$ of isometries of its factors acting transitively, so all points of this spacetime are equivalent, this universe is filled with homogeneous EM field.

A paper that highlights the differences and similarities between Bertotti–Robinson's  and Melvin's solutions is

- Garfinkle, D., & Glass, E. N. (2011). *Bertotti-Robinson and Melvin Spacetimes*, [doi:10.1088/0264-9381/28/21/215012](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/28/21/215012), [arXiv:1109.1535](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1535).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the arXiv paper.  This is interesting!  Sadly, I don't have access to the first link.  What is it?

Comment: I'm also surprised by the $\text{AdS}_2$, since there is no cosmological constant in the solution I've shown here.

Comment: The first link is simply the officially published version of the arXiv preprint (they might differ by some copyediting). The $\text{AdS}_2$ is a factor, not the whole spacetime.